# Why can I still access vector data after resizing?

Tags: c++, vector, stdvector

The following code doesn't throw an error:

```
int main()
{
typedef std::vector<int> intstack;

intstack mystack;

mystack.push_back(7);
mystack.push_back(8);
mystack.push_back(9);

mystack.pop_back();
std::cout << mystack.size(); //prints 2
std::cout << mystack[2]; // prints 9
return 0;
}
```

I would have thought the line `std::cout << mystack[2]` would throw an error because the vector has been resized by the `pop_back` operation. Why is the data still accessible? Is it because the data in the underlying array is still there and the vector `pop_back` operation only modifies the iterators?

Comment: Accessing `mystack[2]` is Undefined Behavior.  Throwing an error would be defined.

Comment: To elaborate, ``std::vector`` only does bounds checking when you use the ``at()`` method, not when you use the ``[]`` operator.

Comment: Another aspect of this is that `vector` doesn't release memory unless you call `shrink_to_fit` (or `swap` with e.g. a temporary).  Even `clear()` and `resize()` never reduce capacity.  So, the memory for `mystack[2]` is definitely still owned by the `vector`, it's just that after popping that value the `vector` could theoretically do something like set the memory to read only or put an sentinel "trap" value in there, though in reality it's usually `vector`s of class objects where the destructor leaves the object in an unusable state that are dangerous to access after such a pop.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`std::vector` `operator[]` does not perform range checks.

the `at()` [member function](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/at/) does.

Your line `std::cout << mystack[2]` has undefined behavior.